# storing list item code in database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have the following structure:

```
<ul>
<li code=12>C++</li>
<li code=5>Java</li>
<li code=17>PHP</li>
</ul>
```

when the user click on  save button the form will be submit to PHP function.
i want  to pass 12,5,17(list item codes) as array to PHP function(with $_POST array) to store it in the database.
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the numbers, or the text inside of the list items?

Comment: -1. Please do some basic research. This is called AJAX and has been probably the most talked about development in internet technologies for years and years and years...

Comment: Who voted this question down? It clearly explains all of the requirements and asks for suggestions. Just because the OP doesn't know understand the browsers HTTP POST interface doesn't mean that it's a bad question.

Comment: i know that i can do it using AJAX, but i search for something to allow me to send array of codes on submit and not separately, for example store array of codes in hidden array(<input type=hidden name='codes_array[]' value=code_array/>),is that the best practice?

Answer (score 6):

```
// Event handler for when you click the button
$("button.save").click(function () {
    var codes = [];

    // For each of your li's with a code attribute
    $("li[code]").each(function () {

        // Stuff the code into an array
        codes.push($(this).attr("code"))
    });

    // You can't post an array, so we turn it into a comma separated string
    codes = codes.join();

    // Do a post request to your server resource
    $.post("/path-to-your-php-code/", {"codes" : codes}, function (response) {
        // Handler for successful post request

        alert("The ajax request worked!");
    });

});
```

You will also need to parse the string of codes in your php, which will be available in

```
$_POST["codes"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('url.php', {
      li1:$("li:eq(0)").text(),
      li2:$("li:eq(1)").text(),
      li3:$("li:eq(2)").text()}, function(){
   alert('done');
});
```

Comment: thank you for replay, but i want to send the code array when   the form is submitted(when user  click save button),so when the user click save, hidden array will be send to a function, this  function will get array code using $_post['code_array_name'], and store it in the database, can we do this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Adam's answer, to pass the data in a way that PHP will recognize as an array, you can use the fact that in HTTP you can POST the same key with more than one value. I've noticed empirically that PHP treats multi-valued keys terminating with "[]" as arrays. So, you can use this (untested) code to accomplish your original goal:

```
// Event handler for when you click the button
$("button.save").click(function () {
    var codes = [];

    // For each of your li's with a code attribute
    $("li[code]").each(function () {

        // Stuff the code into an array
        codes.push($(this).attr("code"));
    });

    // >>>>> Set up the post data to be recognized as an array by PHP
    var post_data = [];
    $(codes).each(function() {
        post_data.push({
            name: "codes[]",
            value: this
        });
    });

    // Do a post request to your server resource
    $.post("/path-to-your-php-code/", post_data, function (response) {
        // Handler for successful post request

        alert("The ajax request worked!");
    });

});
```